# Can I get access to the Garmin Health API as a hobbyist?

Tags: garmin

I'm a fairly new programmer and experienced runner and have been going through the Garmin Health API and have planned on making an application.

My first idea is for simply getting the average time after doing 10x400m which is a test I do almost every month. I'm fairly certain I can do this with the health API but I don't know how to request it as a hobbyist and fairly new programmer.

The app would be beneficial both for me as a programmer and the team I'm running for.

**Can I get access to the Garmin Health API as a hobbyist?**

Answer (score 10):

I requested this API from Garmin a while ago, and they were clear in their emails that it's only available to Enterprise developers. I'd suggest Fitbit as they maintain a free API for all users.

Answer (score 5):

Garmin will not give you access unless you're an Enterprise developer.

What you can do is connect your Garmin account to Strava, and then pull your data down using the Strava API's

Comment: The problem with the "use Strava" approach assumes that the data I'm interested in is synced with Strava.  It's not activity data I want, but rather health data like daily step count, etc, which (unless I'm missing something) isn't synced to Strava.

Answer (score 3):

Have you developed anything on this for your own data?  I would suggest starting there.  You have access to all the fit files from your own garmin connect account and you'll then basically have an MVP that you could host on the web.

Once you've done that, it's simple enough for your team to share their files with you, albeit a bit of a pain in the arse.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Leahy has the right idea, linking Garmin to Strava (free to do) and pulling from Strava APIs works for all activity data that you record. Where that plan falls short is if you're hoping to supplement sleep data, resting heart rate, steps, or any of the other health metrics that Garmin won't sync as activities to Strava

Answer (score 0):

There is now an api you can download from npm and connect to it directly:

https://github.com/abrander/garmin-connect

Comment: this is an unoffical reverse engineering